# How to check if object with no names exists in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am building a javascript function where I want to add an object to an array IF it is not already present, if it is I just want to update value.

My objects look like this:

```
[{31652237148248: 12}, {4365124714824: 4}]
```

How can I check the Array if there is an object with the ID of 31652237148248?

I tried this but it did not work:

```
var index = cartItems.findIndex((obj => obj[id] == id));
```

Comment: Your code is looking to see if the id is equal to the value of the object....

Comment: It is used for Shopify cart

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [in operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) to check if the id is a property of the object:

```js
const cartItems = [{31652237148248: 12}, {4365124714824: 4}];

const id = '4365124714824';

const index = cartItems.findIndex((obj => id in obj));

console.log(index);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly fine!

Answer (score 2):

You are looking to see if the value of objects property is equal to the id. `31652237148248` is never going to equal `12`

so you can just do a type of

```
var index = cartItems.findIndex(obj => typeof obj[id] !== undefined);
```

you can do a truthy check - will fail if it is a falsey value.

```
var index = cartItems.findIndex(obj => obj[id]);
```

you can use object keys and includes or if first is equal

```
var index = cartItems.findIndex(obj => Object.keys(obj).includes(id));
var index = cartItems.findIndex(obj => Object.keys(obj)[0] === id);
```

A bunch of ways to do it

Personally a better way is just to use an object and not an array for the data.

```
var items = {31652237148248: 12, 4365124714824: 4}

const addItem = (id, count) => {
  cartItems[id] = (cartItems[id] || 0) + count
}

const getArray = () => 
  Object.entries(items).map(([key, count]) => ({ [key]: count }))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
let add = (obj,arr,k=Object.keys(obj)[0]) => 
           arr.some( o=> (k in o)&&(o[k]=obj[k]) ) || arr.push(obj)
```

```js
let data = [{31652237148248: 12}, {4365124714824: 4}]

let add = (obj,arr,k=Object.keys(obj)[0]) => 
           arr.some( o=> (k in o)&&(o[k]=obj[k]) ) || arr.push(obj) 

// TEST
add({31652237148248: 15}, data);
console.log('update',data);

add({666: 15}, data);
console.log('add',data);
```